# Fatal exception in Login application using hostinger

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, fatal-error

hi iam depressed literally, the login code that i tried for learing to connect app to mysql is working fine with wampserver.
but on going online thorugh Hostliner iam getting fatal exception on postexecute function.

pls help iam not able to forward in my app.

iam pasting my log and background task java code.

```js
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by prabeesh on 7/14/2015.
 */
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
  AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
      this.ctx =ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://kamster.esy.es/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://kamster.esy.es/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
               InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
               IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if(method.equals("login"))
        {
           String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line  = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
      {
          Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
        else
      {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
          alertDialog.show();
      }

    }
}
```

Log

```
10-29 12:29:22.941  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ java.io.EOFException
```

10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:95)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:179)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:628)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
10-29 12:29:22.942  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:92)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:23)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-29 12:29:22.943  12011-12028/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-29 12:29:22.945  12011-12011/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
10-29 12:29:22.945  12011-12011/com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo, PID: 12011
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:124)
            at com.easyway2in.mysqldbdemo.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:23)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    --------- beginning of system

thanks